# How to remove %20 from url in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, python-webbrowser

How do I remove %20 from url in my code?

```
elif 'launch' and 'open' in voice_note:
    print('opening...')
    start_url = "https://www."
    end_url = ".com"
    urllib.parse.unquote(voice_note)
    play_sound_from_polly('Displaying the result, sir')
    webbrowser.open(start_url + voice_note.replace('open', '').replace('%20', '') + end_url)
    exit()
```

Here is a image of what it opens [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO8qm.png)

Comment: Have you copy/pasted your post title into Google yet?

Comment: Check the contents of `voice_note` and see if that's what you expect or not.

Comment: It's not `%20`. It's a space. Do `.strip()` after removing `'open'` or change second `replace` to remove spaces.

Comment: `%20` is how spaces are encoded in URLs.

Comment: %20 is a space so you can remove space in voice_note by doing voice_note .strip()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
webbrowser.open(start_url + voice_note.replace('open', '').replace('%20', '') + end_url)
```

Use strip() function:

```
webbrowser.open(start_url + voice_note.replace('open', '').strip() + end_url)
```

Or simply put:

```
webbrowser.open(start_url + voice_note.replace('open', '').replace(' ', '') + end_url)
```

The reason is you are trying to replace '%20' and not a space.
%20 is an encoded value of space in a url.

Answer (score 2):

%20 is the url encoding for the space : ' ' character, so you want to strip or replace the ' ' in your url string.